# How to use NGINX to forward the request to Docker Microservice

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I wanted to use NGINX as a reverse proxy to forward the request to microservices.
Both NGINX and Microservices are hosted on docker container.

Below is my nginx.conf file

```
    worker_processes 1;

    events { worker_connections 1024; }

    #test

    http {

        sendfile on;

        # upstream docker-nginx {
        #     server nginx:80;
        # }

        upstream admin-portal {
            # server admin-portal:9006;
            server xx.xx.xx.xx:9006;
            # server localhost:9006;

        }

server {
            listen 8080;

            location / {
                proxy_pass         http://admin-portal;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }


        }


    }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl 
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ../../conf/
    volumes:
    - ./mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - cloud


networks:
  cloud:
   driver: bridge
```

- I am able to access nginx home page by **localhost:8080**
- admin-portal is a microservice running on 9006 port

But if I do  **localhost:8080/admin-portal/** I am getting below error

`nginx_1  | 2018/07/04 07:08:17 [error] 7#7: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin-portal/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: your-domain.com, request: "GET /admin-portal/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
nginx_1  | 2018/07/04 07:08:17 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: your-domain.com, request: "GET /admin-portal/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
nginx_1  | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [04/Jul/2018:07:08:17 +0000] "GET /admin-portal/ HTTP/1.1" 404 170 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
admin-portal/`

Please suggest what changes I need to do to forward the request to admin-portal using nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
upstream admin-portal {
    server 127.0.0.1:9006;
}
```

it should be :

```
upstream admin-portal {
    server 172.17.0.1:9006;
}
```

With `172.17.0.1` is ip address gateway of containers.

Or `docker inspect containermicroservice_id` then get ip address of that container.

```
 upstream admin-portal {
    server ipaddressofmicroservicecontainer:9006;
}
```

Put ip address of server into

```
        server_name    localhost ipaddressofserver www.example.com;
```

then access `http://ipaddressofserver:8080/admin-portal`

Comment out this part:

```
#server {
#            listen       8080;
#            server_name     your-domain.com www.your-domain.com;
#            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
#            index  index.html index.htm;

#            error_page  404              /404.html;
#            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#                root   html;
#            }
        }
```

Comment: I have made the changes that you have mention `172.17.0.1` also I tried with `docker inspect admin-portal` and put the **IPAddress** of the container Still the exception is same

Comment: put `proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";` after `proxy_redirect` line. remove `/` at the end  `proxy_pass http://admin-portal;`

Comment: I have made the changes that you have suggested, Updated the same into my question but didnt work out

Comment: are you sure microservice is working ? using curl to check it, what is error log for now ?

Comment: move `upstream admin-portal` part to the top of configuration file, I mean before the first `server` part

Comment: Yes microservices are working. If I do `sudo curl localhost:9006` i get expected response. and if i try to access it by `localhost:8080/admin-portal/ ` the same error as I mention in my question. . And moving upstream part at the top means inside `http {` just above the `include       mime.types;`  ??

Comment: did you move the `upstream admin-portal` and the second `server` to before the first `server` part ? or seperate 2 `server` to 2 files

Comment: should be set `proxy_redirect off;`

Comment: still see `server 127.0.0.1:9006;` did you change ip address ?

Comment: Yes, I made that changes and now the error is changed to `can not get Cannot GET /admin-portal/`

Comment: try to change   `listen       8080;` to `listen       8081;` in second `server` part, or comment out the second `server` part if no need, and try again

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh remove the second `server` part and test again

Comment: Did the same I am getting `can not get Cannot GET /admin-portal/`

Comment: did you use `www.example.com/admin-portal` ?

Comment: did you mean I need to curl try to access it from browser http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/www.example.com/admin-portal/  ??

Comment: just added into the answer. http://ipaddressofserver:8080/admin-portal after you add `server_name    ipaddress www.example.com;` in nginx file

Comment: I have made the changes as per your suggetion also Updated in my question but it still the same `can not get Cannot GET /admin-portal/`

Comment: : If I login into bash control of nginx i.e `sudo docker exec -it nginx bash` and then hit **http://admin-portal:9006/testApi** I am getting expected output, But from outside container i.e **localhost:8080/admin-portal/testApi** I am still getting `get Cannot GET /admin-portal/testApi` .  .  .

Comment: Try to test `ipaddressofnginx:8080/admin-portal/testApi` ? @AnandDeshmukh

Comment: Yes same with the `ipaddressofnginx:8080/admin-portal/testApi`

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh just edited the answer, pls check step -by step

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh `curl with ip address of server from outside docker container

Comment: I have done the changes also updated the conf file in code. I am getting the same error message. I have also added Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in case if I missed something in those files

Comment: add my skype : thanh.nguyen2891

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am able to forward the request to admin-portal using `http://ipaddress:8080/` but when I change my location to  `location /admin-portal { other code` in conf file  and hit `http://ipaddress:8080/admin-portal/` I am getting 404